# Ubuntu 22.04 Chuwi herobook-pro audio dummy output

Tags: sound

as the title suggests, I have a chuwi herobook pro with dual boot windows and ubuntu 22 installed.

My problem is that with ubuntu the sound does not work while if I start windows it works regularly.

I have tried to follow a lot of guides but with no results.

Below I leave the result of aplay -l and inxi -Axx
Thanks

```
**** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
scheda 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 1: HDMI1 (*) []
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 2: HDMI2 (*) []
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], dispositivo 3: HDMI3 (*) []
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
```

````
Audio:
 Device-1: Intel Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High
   Definition Audio
   driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl bus-ID: 00:0e.0
   chip-ID: 8086:3198
 Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-27-generic running: yes
 Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
 Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
   ```
````

Answer (score -2):

I arrived to this post perhaps too late. Anyway, i hope i can help.

I have Linux Mint Debian Edition 5 (elsie) x86_64 dualbooted with Windows 10.

Here are my results of both commands you executed:

`aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`inxi -Axx`

```
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:0e.0 chip ID: 8086:3198 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.10.0-21-amd64
```

Seems your Ubuntu is only using HDMI for sound.
Look to this line, you haven't:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And also i see you are using `sof-audio-pci-intel-apl`.
I'm using `snd_hda_intel`.

Perhaps my answer can help to solve your problem.

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer, as it does not provide a solution.